# How to add tool tips for xamarin forms wpf application

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.wpf

I am working on xamarin forms wpf application. I have a requirement of showing tooltips when the user mouseover. Please suggest any idea on how to add tooltips to xamarin forms wpf application. Thank you.

Comment: This tooltips is for android and ios but the code is there so you may be able to translate it
https://github.com/CrossGeeks/TooltipSample